# Adding settings link to plugin doesn't work

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I'm trying to add a "settings" link to my plugin on the plugins page. I used this code, which I found on various sites and also in the documentation, but it simply doesn't work (the link doesn't show).

What did I do wrong?

```
function apd_settings_link( $links ) {
    $url           = get_admin_url() . "options-general.php?page=my-plugin";
    $settings_link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . __('Settings', 'textdomain') . '</a>';
    array_unshift( $links, $settings_link );
    return $links;
}

add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'apd_settings_link');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working and tested. Activate your plugin you will see the settings link

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'apd_settings_link' );
function apd_settings_link( array $links ) {
    $url = get_admin_url() . "options-general.php?page=my-plugin";
    $settings_link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . __('Settings', 'textdomain') . '</a>';
      $links[] = $settings_link;
    return $links;
  }
```

Comment: The code worked when I put in in my plugin main file. It seems like I had it in the wrong place before that. I included a file called init.php in my main file like so:
    require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/apd-init.php';
And there I put my code before, which didn't work. How is that?

Comment: got the point. check plugin_basename(__FILE__) not showing your main plugin file :). define( 'EXAMPLE_ABSPATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'EXAMPLE__FILE__', __FILE__ );
define( 'EXAMPLE_BASENAME', plugin_basename( Example__FILE__ ) );
in your main plugin file. and apd-init.php file change the plugin file to add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . 'EXAMPLE_BASENAME, 'apd_settings_link');

Comment: Thank you, that was actually my problem. Calliing plugin_basename(FILE) from apd-init.php would give me the wrong file name. So I defined it the way you did in your example.